# Why is it possible to override some functions in extensions?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Just curious on how it works, why is it possible to override some functions from extensions but not others? 
E.g.

```
class SomeClass { }

extension UIViewController {
    func testFunction(bool: Bool) { }
    func someOtherFunction(someClass: SomeClass) { }
}

class testViewController: UIViewController {
    override func testFunction(bool: Bool) { }
    override func someOtherFunction(someClass: SomeClass) { }
}
```

In this case the FIRST one is fine, as it only contains a bool, but the SECOND one is not, since it takes my class object. 
So the second one will throw `Declarations from extensions cannot be overriden yet`, but that's obviously not true since I am doing it in the line above.

Comment: Related? [Can you override between extensions in Swift or not? (Compiler seems confused!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109006/can-you-override-between-extensions-in-swift-or-not-compiler-seems-confused)

Comment: Also related: [Swift dispatch to overridden methods in subclass extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37492897/2976878). Being able to override extension methods in this case is merely an Obj-C compatibility thing, hence why it fails for a method that has a parameter which is not directly representable in Obj-C.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492897/swift-dispatch-to-overridden-methods-in-subclass-extensions. And I had an interesting discussion with the Swift folks here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8010